# Replace \n with <br> in JSON string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, user-interface

I have a function to grab text data as JSON, which then is stringified. 
I'm trying to display this data in a modal in my web application, however the string appears in the HTML like this:

> {"body":"---\nbl_playout_user: BLplayout\n\n# Playout config
>   values\nbl_playout_image_drive_mount:
>   '\\Paparazzi\Images'\nbl_playout_image_path:
>   'I:'\nbl_playout_machine_role: Primary\nbl_playout_network_name:
>   ABC1\nbl_playout_stand_alone_mode: 0\nbl_playout_run_mode:
>   HD\nbl_playout_format: AJA\nbl_playout_resolution:
>   720P\nbl_playout_logo_override: ABC\nbl_playout_default_header:
>   BottomLine\nbl_playout_sponsor_on: 15000\nbl_playout_sponsor_off:
>   60000\nbl_playout_media_ball_on: 15000\nbl_playout_media_ball_off:
>   15000\nbl_playout_page_engine_working_directory: '{{
>   bl_templates_root_dir
>   }}\SC14_Templates'\nbl_playout_schema_file_path: '{{
>   bl_templates_root_dir
>   }}\SC14_Templates\BLMaster.xsd'\nbl_playout_default_swatch_path: '{{
>   bl_templates_root_dir
>   }}\SC14_Templates\003_BtmLn_deliverable_ele\still_ele\RDBL_GENERIC_SWATCH.png'\nbl_playout_default_logo_path:
>   '{{ bl_templates_root_dir
>   }}\SC14_Templates\003_BtmLn_deliverable_ele\still_ele\default_team_logo.png'\n"}

I would like the instances of `\n` to be replaced with a `<br>` so it shows up properly in the HTML, however my function doesn't seem to be doing the trick. Any ideas as to why? I'm very stumped.

```
var stringData = JSON.stringify(data);
stringData = stringData.replace(new RegExp('\r?\n','g'), '<br />');
return stringData;
```

Comment: Can't you use a `pre` element? BTW, posting an image instead of data is less than ideal.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Do you want to show the encoded `\n` *inside* the string values as line breaks? That would be weird since strings in JSON cannot contain literal line breaks. Or do you want to convert *literal* line breaks between, e.g. object properties. What is your desired output?

Comment: I would like the var `stringData` to show up in the HTML as a key/val pair, where each part of the string with a semicolon corresponds to a key/val pair. At the end of the key/val pair, I want a line break so each key/val is on a singular line.

Comment: You probably mean a colon `:` instead of a semicolon.

Comment: As @squint said, you should put the value inside a `<pre>` tag instead.

Comment: I added the `pre` tag in lieu of the `p` and this is what happens http://i.stack.imgur.com/O2jbO.png

Comment: So you want the `body` key and outer braces to be include in the output too? If so, then @FelixKling's comment about it being odd to display actual breaks in a string would seem important. If it's just the value of the `body` key, then that makes more sense.

Comment: I think you should *parse* JSON, get the value of `body` and then *parse* and format that value. Simply replacing line breaks (even encoded ones) in the raw JSON string wouldn't be useful IMO.

Comment: @FelixKling I guess yeah that's a better way of wording it. How would I approach doing something like that instead? Sorry, this is my first time working with JSON parsing so I've tried a lot of different methods to no avail.

Comment: So this is like YAML inside JSON. You only want the YAML to be displayed? How complex will it get? You sure you won't need a full YAML parser?

Comment: @squint: Oh, good catch. Didn't notice that it's YAML.

Comment: @Jason: If you use a (hypothetical) YAML parser, it would be as simple as `preElement.innerHTML = yamlParser.parse(JSON.parse(json).body);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on comments and building on other answer..

```
var json = JSON.parse(stringData);
json.body = body = json.body.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");

// and then if you needed it in a string you can do this again
stringData = JSON.stringify(json);
```

Comment: var doo = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(pageText)); var extra = doo.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/gm, "<br>"); this doesn't break any cross-origin rules for the browser and I guess now I will set it to the innerHtml of an element for jsPdf...

Answer (score 7):

Try this.

```
stringData = stringData.replace(new RegExp("\\\\n", "g"), "<br />");
```

or this

```
stringData = stringData.replace(/\\n/g, "<br />");
```

Comment: This is all you need: stringData = stringData.replace(/\\n/g, '<br />');

Comment: The OP clarified their question. What you are proposing is not what they want. It would replace every occurrence of the character sequence `\n`, not line breaks.

Comment: @FelixKling: I'm actually unsure about that now. There's only a single key/value pair in the JSON, and the value of that pair is a string with escape sequences in it.

Comment: @squint: yeah, the OP's new comment helps.